# Why does this acid-base reaction occur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, equilibrium

My teacher told me about the reaction of sodium peroxide with water:

$$\text{Na}_2\text{O}_2 + 2\text{H}_2\text{O} \ce{->} \text{H}_2\text{O}_2 + 2\text{NaOH}$$

Now, the concentration of products may be comparable to that of the reactants (warranting a $\ce{<=>}$ sign instead of $\ce{->}$), but why does the forward reaction occur at all?

Hydrogen peroxide is a stronger acid than water, and sodium peroxide isn't a stronger base than sodium hydroxide.

In an acid-base reaction, a strong acid converts to a weaker acid and a strong base to a weaker one. The opposite seems to be happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\ce{HO2-}$ is a weaker base than $\ce{NaOH}$. but $\ce{O2^2-}$ is much stronger base than $\ce{HO2-}$ and does not occur in water solutions in significant amount. But its salts ( sometimes in the form of hydrates ) can be precipitated at highly alkaline solutions of hydrogen peroxide.

Additionally, lack of product presence supports the respective equilibrium reactions to be pushed forward. There would be mix of hydrated $\ce{Na+}$, $\ce{OH-}$, $\ce{H2O2}$ and $\ce{HO2-}$.

---

Aside of that, a weaker acid convert a salt of a stronger acid to the respective acid, even if not quantitatively. As all is about the equilibrium and initial concetrations of involves acids and salts.

---

The equation should be rather written like this:

$$\ce{Na2O2(s) + H2O -> 2 Na+(aq) + HO2-(aq) + OH-(aq)} \label{1}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{HO2-(aq) + H2O <=> H2O2(aq) + OH-(aq)}\label{2}\tag{2}$$

Note that after the $\eqref{1}$ is performed, there is abut the same concentration of $\ce{OH-}$ and $\ce{HO2-}$. But while there is $\pu{55.x mol/L}\  \ce{H2O}$, there is still none $\ce{H2O2}$. So even if $\ce{H2O2}$ is stronger acid than $\ce{H2O}$, and even if $\ce{OH-}$ is stronger base than $\ce{HO2-}$, the reaction $\eqref{2}$ goes forward until the equilibrium is reached.

BTW, $\ce{H2O2}$ does not convert to $\ce{H2O}$, it is not a redox reaction.

Comment: I don't think I understand. Basically, my problem is: if the forward reaction occurs to near completion, the acid on the product side should be weaker than the acid at the reactant side, and the base at the product side should be weaker than the base at the reactant side (i.e., it should dissociate less).
In this reaction, the acid on the product side is H2O2. The acid on the reactant side is H2O. Wouldn't H2O2 convert to H2O? And then, wouldn't the concentration of H2O be greater than that of H2O2? But here, the concentration of H2O2 is higher. Ditto for bases.

Answer (score 2):

I think your teacher's version of hydrolysis of sodium peroxide is straight out from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_peroxide) article, which follows the reference 1. Wikipedia states that:

> Sodium peroxide hydrolyzes to give sodium hydroxide and hydrogen peroxide according to the reaction: $$\ce{Na2O2 + 2H2O -> 2NaOH + H2O2}$$

However, even though it can seemingly be considered to go to the completion at once as above equation showed (because of the extremely high reactivity of $\ce{Na2O2}$), actual total reaction should establish as combination of two following reactions, one in equilibrium, as Poutnik showed in the answer elsewhere:

$$\ce{Na2O2 + H2O -> NaOH + HO-O^-Na^+} \tag1$$
$$\ce{HO-O^-Na^+ + H2O <=> HO-OH + OH- + Na+} \tag2$$

Keep in mind that $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{H2O2 + H2O <=> HO-O^- + H3O^+}$ reaction is $11.75$ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide)) and hence $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ of the reaction $(2)$ should be $14 - 11.75 = 2.25$ (or $K_\mathrm{b} = 5.62 \times 10^{-3}$). Therefore, this equilibrium is feasible with $[\ce{HO-O^-}] \gt [\ce{H2O2}]$.

---

Because of the high reactivity (e.g., Ref.2) of $\ce{Na2O2}$ seemingly misguided the final outcome of sought reaction. It is note worthy that anhydrous $\ce{Na2O2}$ cannot be prepared by $\ce{H2O2 + 2 NaOH}$, which gives $\ce{Na2O2.8H2O}$ instead even at high temperature. However, anhydrous $\ce{Li2O2}$ has been prepared by this method (Lithium and Sodium Peroxides in pages 979-980 of Ref.1).

**References:**

1. E. Dönges, “Section 18: Alkali Metals,” In *Handbook of Preparative Inorganic Chemistry, Volume 1*; 2nd Edition; Georg Brauer, Editor (Reed F. Riley, trans. Ed.); Academic Press, Inc.: New York, NY, 1963, pp. 950-992 (ISBN-13 : 978-0121266011).
2. Hector Russell Carveth of Roessler and Hasslacher Chemical Co. (New York, NY), “Process of producing sodium peroxide,” *US Patent* **1931**, 1,796,241.